# Unwanted white space on right side of page

Tags: html, css, layout, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am building a responsive site. On the large desktop size, I seem to have a bit of white space on the right side of the large sliding banner. I am guessing this is due to some css in the slider causing this. This white space seems to be pushing outside of the boundaries of the body tag. You can see this by moving the horizontal scroll bar to the right. The framework this is built on is Twitter Bootstrap 3.

The slider I used is called FlexSlider.

I would post HTML and CSS, but since I am not totally sure where to start, there would be a lot of it and I am not sure how helpful it would be.

Thanks for any help.

URL to live page: http://sevenclanscasino.designangler.com/warroad/warroad-home

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The footer tag  is overflowing out .. change/update the css that is applied to this tag.

```
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, main, nav, section, summary {
    display: block;
    width: 99%;
}
```

I just tried setting the width to 99% as above.

Comment: Wow, great catch. I didn't even think of the footer sadly. Thank you very much. This probably saved me a ton of time.

Comment: thankyou .. you are welcome .. the inspect element in the console helped me find it.

Comment: Yea, I use that too, but didn't even think to check the footer I guess.

Answer (score 0):

It's a CSS rule:

```
.flexslider {
    margin: 0 0 20px;
    background: #fff;
    border: 4px solid #fff;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -o-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
    -o-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
    zoom: 1;
}
```

You must to comment this lines to see the change:

```
background: #fff;
border: 4px solid #fff;
```

Comment this line and you will not have this white space.

Luiggi

Comment: This helped with the bars going across matching up with the image, but the white-space on the right side is still there.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to modify it? please, and tell me something, if you want my email send me a private message.

```
.flexslider {
    margin: 0px 0px 20px;
    position: relative;
 /*   background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% #FFF;
    border: 4px solid #FFF;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);*/
}
```

I comment this lines, and the white space it's not on the page!

Tell me something

Luiggi

Comment: A J helped me solve the issue. It was related to negative margins on the row class in Bootstrap. Thanks for the feedback though.